# How to inject an e4view with Guice injection

Tags: dependency-injection, eclipse-rcp, e4

I am working on an existing Eclipse RCP based on Luna which consists of 99% 3.x API. We want to change this in an ongoing process; so when I was given the task of creating a new view, I wanted to use the new (in Luna, anyways) e4view element for the org.eclipse.ui.views extension point.

My problem is that part of the RCP uses xtext and thus, several components are available by using Guice.

I am now stranded with something like this

```
public class MyViewPart
{
    @Inject // <- should be injected via Guice (I used @com.google.inject.Inject, otherwise E4DI would complain)
    ISomeCustomComponent component;

    @PostConstruct // <- should be called and injected via E4 DI
    public void createView(Composite parent)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

To get this injected with Guice, I would usually use an `AbstractGuiceAwareExecutableExtensionFactory` (as usually done in Xtext contexts) like this:

```
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
      <e4view
            class="my.app.MyExecutableExtensionFactory:my.app.MyViewPart"
            id="my.app.view"
            name="my view"
            restorable="true">
      </e4view>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

But I did not expect this to work, because I thought it would bypass the E4 mechanism (actually, it seems to be the other way round and the *e4view.class* element seems to ignore the extension factory and just uses `my.app.MyViewPart` to inject it with E4DI. To be sure, I have set a class loading breakpoint to `MyViewPart` which is hit from `ContextInjectionFactory.make()`).

As I said, I didn't expect both DI frameworks to coexist without conflict, so I think the solution to my problem would be to put those object which I need injected into the E4 context.

I have googled a bit but I have found multiple approaches, and I don't know which one is the "correct" or "nice" one.

Among the approaches I have found, there are:

1. providing context functions which delegate to the guice injector
2. retrieving the objects from guice and configure them as injector bindings
3. retrieving the objects from guice, obtain a context and put them in the context

(The first two approaches are mentioned in the "Configure Bindings" section of https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/Dependency_Injection)

And of course I could get the objects from Guice in the MyViewPart implementation, but that's not what I want...

**[Edit:]** In the meantime I have explored the options above a bit more:

**Context Functions**

I tried to register the context functions as services in the Bundle Activator with this utility method:

```
private void registerGuiceDelegatingInjection(final BundleContext context, final Class<?> clazz)
{
 IContextFunction func = new ContextFunction()
 {
   @Override
   public Object compute(final IEclipseContext context, final String contextKey)
   {
     return guiceInjector.getInstance(clazz);
   }
 };

 ServiceRegistration<IContextFunction> registration = 
   context.registerService(IContextFunction.class, func,
   new Hashtable<>(Collections.singletonMap(
   IContextFunction.SERVICE_CONTEXT_KEY, clazz.getName()
 )));
}
```

and called `registerGuiceDelegatingInjection()` in the BundleActivator's `start()`  method for each class I needed to be retrieved via Guice.

For some reason, however, this did not work. The service itself was registered as expected (I checked via the OSGi console) but the context function was never called. Instead I got injection errors that the objects could not be found during injection. Maybe the context functions cannot be contributed dynamically but have to be contributed via declarative services, so they are known as soon as the platform starts?

(Answer here is: yes. As the JavaDoc to `IContextFunction` says: *Context functions can optionally be registered as OSGi services [...] to seed context instances with initial values.* - and since the application context already exists when my bundle is started, the dynamically registered service is not seen by the `ContextFactory` in time).

**Injector Bindings**

I quickly found out that this solution does not work for me, because you can only specify an interface-class to implementation-class mapping in the form

```
      InjectorFactory.getDefault().addBinding(IMyComponent.class).implementedBy(MyComponent.class)
```

You obviously cannot configure instances or factories this way, so this is not an option, because I need to delegate to Guice and get Guice-injected instances of the target classes...

**Putting the objects in the context**

This currently works for me, but is not very nice. See answer below.

**[Edit 2:]** As I have reported, putting the objects in the (application) context works for me. The downside is that having the objects in the application context is too global. If I had two or more bundles which would require injection of object instances for another DSL, I would have to take care (e.g., by using `@Named` annotations) to not get the wrong instance injected.

What I would like better is a way to extend the Part's context with which my e4view is created and injected directly. But so far I have not found a way to explicitly target that context when putting in my instances ...

Thanks for any further hints...

Answer (score 1):

Try the processor mechanism of E4: You should be using a (Pre or Post) Processor (along with the PostContextCreate annotation) to register your POJOs into the (global) IEclipseContext.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I understand the doc correctly, to use `@PostContextCreate` I need to add a `lifeCycleURI` property to the application/product. (at least this is what http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4LifeCycle/article.html states). This seems to be too "global" to me and we have several products we are building based on the bundles, and I wouldn't want to modify all the products.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me best so far was getting the IEclipseContext and put the required classes there myself during the bundle activator's start() method.

```
private void registerGuiceDelegatingInjection(final BundleContext context, final Class<?> clazz)
{
  IServiceLocator s = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
  IEclipseContext ctx = (IEclipseContext) s.getService(IEclipseContext.class);
  ctx.set(clazz.getName(), guiceInjector.getInstance(clazz));
}
```

This works at least for now. I am not sure how it works out in the future if more bundles would directly put instances in the context; maybe in the long-term named instances would be needed. Also, for me this works, because the injected objects are singletons, so it does not do any harm to put single instances in the context.

I would have liked the context function approach better, but I could not get it to work so far.